# Xcode iOS Bluetooth connect with Bluetooth speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-privateapi

I have been searching for the past few days for a solution but havent been able to find any.

I am developing app to pair and connect to bluetooth device using a mac address.
I found one private framework API, but even that one i cant make it work, since for some reason i can not include the headers from the private API.

Anyone knows any information? How to achieve this on iOS, or is it 100% impossible to do this at the moment, until Apple decides to open up the bluetooth libraries to the developers?

EDIT: 
I was looking into the BeeTee app, and using the private API BluetoothManager.framework, but for some reason it doesnt work on IOS 10 & Xcode 8.1

Has anyone managed to make it work? 
I know it is private API and most probably wont pass on App Store, but that doesnt matter at this moment, since i am looking just to test the concept, wont need to publish app at this moment.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, only Bluetooth Low Energy is supported directly in iOS. Other Bluetooth devices cannot be connected to directly from code. Could you give more detail on precisely which kind of device you are trying to connect with?

Comment: I am trying to connect any kind of Bluetooth Speaker. At the moment i have JBL Clip 2 and Sony SRS-XB2 that i am trying to work with, but i would like to test with any bluetooth speaker

Comment: Even if i have to use Private Api, like Bluetooth Manager, as i said in the question, i dont need to publish the app to the App Store, it is for internal testing only.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this really. All Bluetooth speakers can be paired with iOS devices. Why would you want to make a connection to a device which already implements a standard protocol like A2DP?

Comment: I want to do it on run time, through the app, instead of referring the users to the settings page. That is the only reason why i want to do it that way. Working on a new solution and managed to implement it on Android already, but i have been struggling with iOS.

Comment: Oh, I see. Apple certainly makes that difficult, deliberately so I think. Good luck with it anyway.